# Joins with SubSonic's REST handler

Tags: c#, rest, subsonic

I've just been playing around with the REST handler and frankly I love it. 0 lines of code and my data is accessible via HTTP? Got to love that. Anyway, the only thing I'm not sure of is whether or not I can access data from more than one table with a REST query via the REST handler. I have header records and data records with a one to many relationship but I'd like to retrieve them as one big splurge of XML. Is there a way I can specify a join via REST without creating views or similar in my DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll have to use a View for this - running joins in a URL doesn't scale too well :)

Comment: Thanks Rob, I thought it through and actually, I don't need the blob of xml I thought I did. It's cleaner and simpler if I just hit the tables for the data I need when I actually need it, rather than getting it all up front.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of the client knowing about the URIs and how to build them for requesting joins is completely unrestful anyway. It's POX at it's best and is a poor choice of naming. I'd suggest removing the rest tag...